# ELK Stack Setup on Google Cloud: Getting Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://localhost:9200 w

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm installing ELK Stack (version 5.2) on Google Cloud Platform as part of a blog post I'm writing. After following instructions from Elastic themselves, I get the following issue

Kibana Dashboard:

[image: Kibana Dashboard]

Any ideas on what's preventing ES and Kibana from communicating?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the issue was with the Java version on Google Cloud. For some reason, 1.7 was installed and ELK stack 5.x requires Jave 1.8. Once I installed 1.8 everything ran fine.